# similar seed words minor sequence difference

Tags: security, mnemonic-seed

I created a wallet weeks back and seemingly restored the seed onto my other 2 devices. Recently I got to notice that I had mistakenly logged into another wallet with identical seed words but I different word sequence. Unfortunately when I noticed the discrepancy I wasn't able to tell which seed I generated and which I stumbled upon. From a security stand point should I abandon both wallets? or is there a way to secure both. Note I have funded one the other is empty.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "with identical seed words but I different word sequence"?

Comment: Ok. Let me try.

Comment: Example the seed 12 words are  A B C D H I J K P Q R S W X Y Z, when I typed in the exact words but wrong sequence ( i.e placing words I and H in wrong order)   A B C D I H J K P Q R S W X Y Z, it restored successfully a different wallet

Comment: This is highly improbable. There is a checksum in the wallet mnemonic which prevents this sort of inversion from happening, with something like a 1:16,000 probability.

Comment: I don't think the checksum prevents it, perhaps makes it highly improbable. Well you can imagine my surprise when I noticed it. Is there a way to add another layer of security to the seed, as I cannot figure out which one I actually generated

Comment: I would suggest generating a new seed, then tansferring your funds to a new wallet.